# Ajax Status 200 returns Error

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

I am using ajaxForm, but this one is acting strange. I am calling:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {

  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  }
});
```

The form calls a function which returns in the end:

```
$arrReturn['LNK'] = $fn;
print json_encode($arrReturn);
```

But I'm landing in the error with the correct return values:

```
Array{"LNK":"1437640345.xlsx"}
```

I've tried to remove the dataType, set a header in my called function, build the json String all by myself, but nothing changed anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your error? `HTTP 200` means "The request has succeeded."

Comment: that is the problem. I get a 200 OK Header but the Ajax Form leads to the error function, not the success!

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          success: function (res) {
           // your process
           }
           ,
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
       });
```

Comment: That is more or less the same I already have. But I've removed my dataType, added url and data. But still no success. Still landing in the error function with a Header 200 OK.

Comment: 200 OK is not an error. It means you process is completed successfully.

Comment: I know. But I am still running into the error loop from the ajax call. And not the success

Comment: Can you please post what you are getting error exactly?

Comment: I already did. I do NOT get an error. Status Code says 200 OK. The returned value is as written in the description. But I do not get into success function!

Comment: Maybe it is because I am using .ajaxForm.